# running tagged scenarios using global hooks

Tags: cucumber

I am testing a web application in which I need to delete items (deletion is part of my test scenarios) via UI after all tests are run successfully. This is to ensure a clean data state before starting my next run. I have tagged all the deletion scenarios with a @cleanup tag. What I would like to achieve is the ability to trigger the cucumber run for those tags using at_exit hook or something similar.
Is this something possible?

setup:
cucumber.yml profiles

default: --tags ~@cleanup

cleanup: --tags @cleanup

Comment: Why do you want to delete those objects via Cucumber? You can do it via ordinary Ruby code. Your idea makes your scenarios dependent from each other. It's highly disregarded in "Cucumber book" and "Specification by Example"

Comment: I think you will get better answers to this question if you will ask it [in mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/cukes?hl=en).

Comment: deletion is part of application test scenarios. I would need to do those via the web application itself rather than a db cleanup.

Comment: thanks @AndreyBotalov . I will post the question in the groups too.